# Android push notification offline

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

im trying to implement push notification in my app,already using GCM. But the case is i want it in the way which works offline too. 
i.e: for multiple conditions inside android app it should trigger push notification.

Currently im trying :

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, msg);
notification.contentView = contentView;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,randomNo, notificationIntent, 0);
```

But the problem is,
1.When the app doesnt running ,the notification arrives but it cases screen to blink(becoz i call it using intent).
2.i want to use same class for multiple conditions and forward it to different activities(currently i cant change the intent to another activity based on condtiop).

Comment: Please explain for down voting

Comment: Possibly because it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: its simple. i want push notification offline in android

Comment: Although I didn't down vote is but frankly even I don't understand by "push notification offline"

Comment: what does it mean by offline There are Multiple understanding regarding offline 
I am not using App is in bg 
MY device`s screen is locked and app is either in foreground or back ground 
My internet is offline

Comment: @Rohit5k2  need to use push notification without internet

Comment: @UsmanKurd without internet .how i use push notification service for different conditions in thread ?

Comment: @AnandhaSaravanan: How would you even receive push notification without internet. Internet is the carrier to deliver it on the device.

Comment: using notification manager we can

Comment: Unfortunately U can`t receive Push without Internet For Example When your internet is off do you get message from FB messenger fb Updates , skype ,viber,whats up or any other application the answer is no.

Comment: are you wanna notification implementation locally like user have set the event for particular time at that time notification should be trigger?

Comment: U are mixing local notification with push notificationManager is just a helper Class can be used to push notification to notification bar 
but if Pipeline is empty (Internet is off) then how it can push forward the notification

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi yes anjali. i want local notification which create alert.

Comment: @UsmanKurd sorry to confuse . i just need send local notification to alert the user about some event. meantime each alert call need to take him to different screens on click

Comment: what is your scenario ?

Comment: 1. Example if a user doeskin login application for 1 day -> push a notification  and takes him to login page.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi also if he doesnt entered any details in some of fragments. then i need to show notifcation and takes him to that UI

Answer (score 2):

1) The correct way to send a notification would be `mNotificationManager.notify(...)` like here:

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String title, int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, 
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(id /* ID of notification */, 
            notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

2) You can replace `HomeActivity.class` by a variable which is given in your class constructor or some method as parameter: `Class<?> cls` and just use `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, cls);`

Comment: thanks for your reply. may i know how to pass class from another activity to this method

Comment: currently i can send like,  
private void sendNotification(String message, String title, int id,Context context)

Comment: just use `sendNotification(String message, String title, int id, Class<?> cls, Context context)`

Comment: and then replace `HomeActivity.class` by `cls`

Comment: getting error- > cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.id.myacitivity.java.lang.Class)

Comment: i fixed the issue.thank u so much for your answer

Comment: is there is any way to open fragments instead of passing activities ?

Comment: above solution works only when internet connection is established

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I didn't know that... there's not really a way to open fragments, since you can't directly open them with an Intent. You could set an extra in the intent though and open the fragment in the receiving activity depending on that extra (e.g. in the activity's `onNewIntent()` method which you can override).